# Check Position which hold ID in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am doing chat Application. I want to put newly coming message item in top position of RecyclerView.For this, I want to match coming Id with all Id which are stored in ArrayList in particular position. How Can I search ID with position in My code. Please some idea.
My code is below

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChatViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (chatList.get(position).modelType == ChatMasterModel.TYPE_USER) {
        try {
            final ChatUserModel userModel = (ChatUserModel) chatList.get(position).modelObj;



            holder.tvBuddyName.setText(userModel.getUserName() + " " + userModel.getUserLastName());
            final String complete_name = userModel.getUserName() + " " + userModel.getUserLastName();
            new ImageLoader(activity).DisplayImage(userModel.getUser_image(), holder.ivChatProfilePic, R.drawable.person_icon);




            holder.chatBuddyList.llChatBuddyItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ChatBuddtDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_id", userModel.getUserId());
                    intent.putExtra("header_name", complete_name);
                    intent.putExtra("user_image", userModel.getUser_image());
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if (chatList.get(position).modelType == ChatMasterModel.TYPE_GROUP) {
        try {
            final ChatGroupModel groupModel = (ChatGroupModel) chatList.get(position).modelObj;
            new ImageLoader(activity).DisplayImage(groupModel.getGroup_iamge(), holder.ivChatProfilePic, R.drawable.person_icon);
            holder.tvBuddyName.setText(groupModel.getGroupMembers());

           /* if (msg_from.contains(groupModel.getGroupMemberId())) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Group contains ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/

            holder.chatBuddyList.llChatBuddyItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ChatBuddtDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("group_id", groupModel.getGroup_id());
                    intent.putExtra("group_member_id", groupModel.getGroupMemberId());
                    intent.putExtra("header_name", groupModel.getGroupMembers());
                    intent.putExtra("user_image", groupModel.getGroup_iamge());
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

}

Comment: what do you want to achieve, actually

Comment: hi @warlock actually I want to put newly chat message in top. Suppose I have 100 friends and no 98 friends sent me a message. So this 98 no friends message should be display in 0 position of RecyclerView...

Comment: You can sort them on the basis of id, when a new message is received, before calling the notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

store timestamp in arralist and sort array with timestamp and send to recyclerview addafter then notifyadapter